# SQL Instance won't start after patching due to SSIS not being installed but has an SSISDB database present

Tags: sql-server, ssis, patch

I have a good database issue to sort and thankfully it does not impact anyone else but me! I have a local SQL 2019 instance installed on my laptop which I use for nothing serious (so it can easily be blasted away and re-installed). But in the spirit of learning, I thought I'd ask the question to see if anyone knows how I would go about fixing this.

My instance does not have SSIS installed, but I do actually have an SSISDB database on here which has been restored from another instance which does have SSIS installed. Then my local SQL instance was patched to CU12 (without my knowledge or consent I would say!). And because I have an SSISDB database on my instance, SQL is now apparently trying to patch SSIS (which is not installed). The SQL service won't start, and I see loads of errors in the error log. Here is a selection of them:

`Starting execution of ISServer_upgrade.SQL`

`Assembly 'ISSERVER' was not found in the SQL catalog of database 'ssisdb'.`

`Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'ISServer_upgrade.sql' encountered error 6528, state 1, severity 16. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.`

I can start the instance if I want by using trace flag 902, so I can get at any data (which isn't necessary anyway). But I don't know how to resolve the situation. I can't uninstall CU12 as it wasn't installed properly, and it does not fully appear in the list of installed updates. I see options to uninstall CU12 relating to the browser and VSS writer, so I guess these were installed successfully. But there's no option to uninstall CU12 for SQL Server in the add/remove programs as you would expect.

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?
Thanks!

Comment: It would be strange if th eexistence of an SSISDB alone triggered  a SSIS runtmime update. What happens if you rename or remove it?

Comment: It surprised me as well Nick! I've been able to replicate it too in my lab, so I'm confident that what I have described has definitely happened. So I just tried renaming the database (using trace flag 902 to start the instance), then removed the trace flag. Then tried starting the service, and it won't start. If I look at the error log I see the same messages as before, but this time it also says "User does not have permission to alter database 'SSISDB', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks."

Comment: Before going with the full uninstall/reinstall option - I would try installing Integration Services.  If you can install that component then it should not be required to upgrade when starting SQL Server.  If that still happens after installing IS - then try creating a new catalog and a new SSISDB database.

Comment: This [blog](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/11/13/sql-server-assembly-isserver-not-found-sql-catalog-database-ssisdb/) suggest that initialing the catalog can work.

Answer (score 1):

So I have some more info. Firstly, you can restore the SSISDB database to an instance that does not have SSIS installed, and it will allow you to browse the SSIS catalog under "Integration Services Catalogs" in SSMS as if SSIS was installed. If I restore the same SSISDB database from the same backup, but call the database a different name, you can't browse the SSIS catalog in this way. You can also patch the instance without all the issues I have described with the renamed SSIS database being present. If you create a blank SSISDB database and then try to patch to CU12, this also works without issues.

I first tried restoring the master database, more just because I was curious to know what it would do. It didn't let me restore master as the backup I had was for a different version (since the engine is now reading CU12, even though the patch didn't properly install.) So then I installed SSIS, and it still continues behaving in the same way. The next thing to try was to create an SSIS catalog, but because there was an SSIS database already there, albeit not created on this instance, it wouldn't let me create the catalog (option was grayed out). Note that I have to use trace flag 902 whenever I want to start the instance up. Next I deleted the existing SSISDB database. This then allowed me to create a new SSIS catalog, which I did. Then I removed trace flag 902, restarted the service, and it started up! At this point I don't believe that CU12 is properly installed, as it's not showing properly in add/remove programs (as previously described.) So the final thing I did was to manually run the CU12 patch again, and it allowed me to run through that process as if CU12 wasn't installed (if it was already installed it wouldn't let me do this.)

Comment: Here is how I ["created a new SSIS catalog"](https://www.sqlshack.com/introduction-to-the-ssis-catalog-database-ssisdb/#:~:text=Creating%20the%20SSIS%20Catalog&text=This%20catalog%20database%20is%20just,select%20%E2%80%9CCreate%20Catalog%E2%80%A6%E2%80%9D.)